# How to scrape the body from a webpage?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a code which extracts the headlines from ESPN NCAA website. But I would like to scrape the entire WEBPAGE. I'm a newbie in coding so would really appreciate if you could help scrape the webpage. I'm finding it difficult to understand the XML tags and to identify them..could any of you please modify this code so that it print all or most of the content on this webpage? Thanks!

```
from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import smtplib


site = urlopen('http://espn.go.com/college-football').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(site)    


for i in soup.findAll('ul', {'class': 'headlines'}):
    for tag in i.findAll('li'):
        for a in tag.findAll({'a' : True, 'title' : False}):            
            print a.text
            print a['href']                                
            print "\n"
```

Comment: The code looks good. Is there a specific question you had?

Comment: Yes. What I wanted to ask is that the above code ONLY extracts the headlines. How do I make it extract all the text in the webpage?

Answer (score 0):

You can also cheat by using [html2text](http://www.aaronsw.com/2002/html2text/) :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract just text content, you can use a class inherited from `HTMLParser` (from the standard library):

```
from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
from StringIO import StringIO                                                             

class DeHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.text = StringIO()
    def handle_data(self, data):
        self.text.write(data.strip())

def text_from_html(html):
    parser = DeHTMLParser()
    parser.feed(html)
    parser.close()
    return parser.text.getvalue()
```

The `handle_data` function of the `DeHTMLParser` class is invoked when a text content in the HTML tree is encountered. The functions just appends the value to a `StringIO` object (string concatenation is not done to avoid creating multiple temporary objects). The `text_from_html` uses the class to get text from a string/unicode (look at `HTMLParser` module documentation for more information).